# Convert Jupyter notebook file from plain text to python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I created yesterday a Jupyter notebook file in Python 3 and saved it. I do not know what bad manipulation I did but today, when I want to reopen this file, I realize that it is in plain text format! Is there a way to revert to a python encoded format?

The file doesn't have extension `ipynb` (It has no extension) ; it looks like this (few first lines):

`````
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 377,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [
    {
     "name": "stderr",
     "output_type": "stream",
     "text": [
      "C:\\Users\\thaly\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\core\\indexing.py:965: SettingWithCopyWarning: \n",
      "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.\n",
      "Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead\n",
      "\n",
      "See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy\n",
      "  self.obj[item] = s\n"
     ]
    }
   ],
   "source": [
    "import pandas as pd\n",
    "\n",````
`````

Comment: has the extension changed?

Comment: Could you be more specific. Show us an sample of the file, is it a JSON which is also plain/text format but the native format of Jupyter notebook? Also notebook are auto saved. Did you run the Jupyter instance on the same home folder? What is your expected output a python file or jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file you have saved is a Jupyter notebook (internally it is a JSON file).

To convert this notebook, you can:

- Just add an extension `.ipynb` to it,
- run Jupyter and open the notebook with it.
- Then you will be able to export the content of the notebook in several format such as Python file.

Comment: Many thanks! I just added the extension `ipynb` as you suggested, and it's now perfect. I don't understand what happened but i'm really relieved!

Answer (score 1):

1. simple open you txt or any file on jupyter notebook
2. go to the rename option and edit the the name of file with .ipynb (Example file.txt to file.ipynb)
3. save it and open again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're trying to open the html file without actually starting the notebook and using a text editor instead? You need to start the notebook, for instance, from IPython.